# Changing an Elmish.WPF model from inside an async function

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, f#, elmish-wpf

What is the accepted way in Elmish.WPF to have a `Binding.cmd` calling an `async` computation expression (CE) allow the *delayed* result of the `async` CE change the shared top-level model?

I want to do this without causing the UI thread to hang or starve (though having it somehow show *busy* is fine).

I tried having a part of the Model be `mutable` and mutating just that part of the record inside the `async` CE.  This failed probably because the `async` CE is operating on its own copy of the Model.

Is there a way to pass a message with the delayed new value up to the top-level `update` function and update the global shared Model?

The functioning test code is in a repo here: [make 'FandCo_SingleCounter` the Startup Project to run and test in VS2022](https://github.com/rfreytag/Elmish.WPF/tree/FandCoExperiments_async_with_mutable_model)

The important bits of my code is:

`MainWindow.XAML` fragment:

```
...begin of <Window>...
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DISPLAY_state}" Width="110" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CMD_get_state}" Content="DO IT!" Width="50" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
    </StackPanel>
...to end of </Window>...
```

`Program.fs` fragment(s):

```
type Model =
  { mutable DISPLAY_state: string
   }

type Msg =
  | CMD_get_state

let init =
  { DISPLAY_state = "foo"
   }

let ASYNC_get_state (m: Model) :Model =
  async {
      Console.WriteLine( "async 0: "
                          + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
                          + " - "
                          + m.DISPLAY_url_state)
      m.DISPLAY_url_state <- "bar"
      Console.WriteLine( "async +: "
                          + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
                          + " - "
                          + m.DISPLAY_state)
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
      Console.WriteLine( "async ++: "
                          + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
                          + " - "
                          + m.DISPLAY_state)
     }
     |> Async.StartImmediate
  Console.WriteLine( "m.Display_url_state 0: "
                 + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
                 + " - "
                 + m.DISPLAY_state)
  Console.WriteLine( "m.Display_state 1: "
                 + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString()
                 + " - "
                 + m.DISPLAY_state)
  { m with DISPLAY_state = "baz" }

let update msg m =
  | CMD_get_state => ASYNC_get_state m

let bindings () : Binding<Model, Msg> list = [
    "DISPLAY_url_state" |> Binding.oneWay (fun m -> m.DISPLAY_url_state)
    "CMD_get_url" |> Binding.cmd CMD_get_url
  ]
...etc...to end of Elmish.WPF Core F# file.
```

The result of this is:

```
async 0: 275 - foo
async +: 591 - bar
async ++: 160 - True
m.Display_state 0: 164 - True
m.Display_state 1: 167 - True
[13:26:18 VRB] New message: CMD_get_state
Updated state:
{ DISPLAY_url_state = "baz" }
[13:26:18 VRB] [main] PropertyChanged DISPLAY_state
[13:26:18 VRB] [main] TryGetMember DISPLAY_state
```

At the end `DISPLAY_state` binding in the MainWindow.XAML updates to the value `baz` and not the desired value `bar`.

How is this *supposed* to be done?

Comment: I am not going to look into this, but have a look at the DemoAsync project in my repo [here](https://github.com/BentTranberg/ElmishXmas). I think it likely is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking through your ElmishXmas (thank you), and am struck (and I am not at all speaking about *your* work!) that so much of Elmish.WPF just works so well that I expected the answer to my question to be more evident in the abundant documentation.

Comment: Very understandable. I believe the documentation for [Elmish.WPF](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF), so far at least, has had to be limited to the specifics of this particular implementation of [Elmish](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/) for the most part, or else the scope would be far too big. There are other implementations, such as [Bolero](https://fsbolero.io/) and the [SAFE](https://safe-stack.github.io/) stack with Fable that also has interesting documentation. By far the most interesting documentation I've found is [The Elmish Book](https://zaid-ajaj.github.io/the-elmish-book).

Comment: You can also find a lot of interesting stuff in the open and the closed issues of the Elmish.WPF repo and other repos such as Bolero, though it's a bit time-consuming to dig out information that way. It was my intention to create more demos and learning material, but my full-time job requires too much attention, so it has been precious little so far.

Comment: Googling code I found in your code led me to [The Elmish Book - Commands section](https://zaid-ajaj.github.io/the-elmish-book/#/chapters/commands/commands).  That helped me finally make sense of [Elmish.WPF - Command Bindings](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#command-bindings).  Would you like some edits to your Docs in case a rookie perspective would help others?  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Brent!

Answer (score 3):

I am the maintainer of Elmish.WPF.

> Is there a way to pass a message with the delayed new value up to the top-level update function and update the global shared Model?

This is not exactly a question specific to Elmish.WPF in the sense that all derivates of [Elmish](https://github.com/elmish/elmish) (and in fact all MVU architectures) have to provide a way to appropriately execute async code that returns a message.

There are two ways to do this with Elimsh (and thus Elmish.WPF):

1. A subscription.  See the `SubModel` sample and especially [this line](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/e9742bdfa8d71786a51aa4e7f96d693621692eca/src/Samples/SubModel.Core/Program.fs#L177).
2. An (Elmish) command.  See the `FileDialogs` sample and especially [these lines](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/e9742bdfa8d71786a51aa4e7f96d693621692eca/src/Samples/FileDialogs.Core/Program.fs#L65-L66).

The Elmish.WPF binding named `cmd` has nothing to do with this.  This binding is named after the WPF interface [`ICommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand).